# Getting NSDate from database and assign it to object NSDate

Tags: ios7, sqlite

I am doing a project that will load data from database and display it in tableView.

I am wondering... What is the right code to be executed for NSDate from database to be assigned into voucher.date

line of code asked=(voucher.date = [[NSNumber alloc](init with sqlite3 statement line);)

Responses will be a great help ! :)

```
NSMutableArray *vouchers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            searchAndClaim *voucher = [[searchAndClaim alloc]init];
            voucher.inquiry_id = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)];
            voucher.name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            voucher.date = [[NSNumber alloc](init with sqlite3 statement line);
            voucher.branch = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            voucher.expDate = [[NSString alloc](init with sqlite3 statement line)];
            [vouchers addObject:voucher];

        }
```

Comment: What is the actual data type of the values in the database?

Comment: date = date, expDate = date also

Comment: SQLite has no `date` data type.

Comment: aa ok.. so I guess I will have to format the date to be string before inserting it into the database. Am I right?

Comment: No, you could use other types. But you must know which one you are using.

Comment: ok thanks! :) I realized that I got string from server and I am trying to pass it to database. I didn't know that there's no date data type in sqlite3. I'm just a newbie in iOS/sqlite3. haha thanks a lot :)